# Wpbakery v5.5.2 backend editor coming up with blank page

Tags: wordpress, visual-editor

I built a site on Wpbakery v5.5.2, as off several days ago the backend editor prompts a message saying the page is blank, but i can still edit in the frontend, has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Possibly clashing with the new editor? install the WordPress classic editor.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark it as the answer below so others can benefit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly clashing with the new editor? install the WordPress classic editor.